# Restrict max speed in tweenmax

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm developing game in Flash and I need to move my movie-clips in a wrap-round way across the screen.
For this I m using `Tweenmax.to()` function provided by greensock.
The function takes 'time' and 'distance' as parameters and applies accleration and deaccleration for the motion itself.

However this takes max-speed of the motion beyond what I want.
Is there a way I could set the max-speed for the motion as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can control the acceleration manually, but to slow speed down you can either set higher value of time:
say, from

```
TweenMax.to(mc, 2, {x:65, y:117});
```

to

```
TweenMax.to(mc, 4, {x:65, y:117});
```

Or use another type of easing - every of them contains its own set of acceleration.
There are a lot of them, you could try to find appropriate one.

There is an [interactive demo](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/), try playing with different easing functions.

Comment: You could also write your own ease-function. It's quite easy, just look at one of the ready-made ones.